# which one is best for offline map in ios?

Tags: ios

I have confused to use offline map in ios when internet connection is on at that time online map get and when user internet connection is off at that time offline map use so which one map used

Please suggest your answer..

Comment: `MapBox` https://www.mapbox.com/

Comment: i can refer that but in this static offline map is used

Comment: What do you mean by `static offline map used`, I can't understand.

Comment: *.mbtiles file to show saved map

Comment: Thats fine, you need to saved data to show offline, its there cache system does it automatically. Its not a problem..

Comment: so when internet connection is available at that time save map data and when internet connection not available at that time map data display this can be possible or not?

Comment: removed irrelevant tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can toggle your Map using `Reachability` class from Apple, see below

```
-(void)setupMapBox{

    RMMapBoxSource *onlineSource = nil;

    Reachability *internet=[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"google.com"];

    if([internet isReachable]){
        //Go for online
        onlineSource = [[RMMapBoxSource alloc] initWithMapID:kMapID];
    }else{
        //If network is not reachable check for offline data if available

        if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"TileJson"]){
            onlineSource=[[RMMapBoxSource alloc] initWithTileJSON:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"TileJson"]];
        }else{
            //If nothing is available show an alert.
            UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Network!" message:@"Please check your network!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];
        }

    }

    if(onlineSource){
        //If resource is avaiable online/offline load the map else NO.

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:onlineSource.tileJSON forKey:@"TileJson"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


        rmMapView = [[RMMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.viewMapContainer.frame andTilesource:onlineSource];

        rmMapView.delegate = self;

        //rmMapView.minZoom = 10;

        rmMapView.zoom = 8; // Set the minimum zoom level



        //Point to London
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
        coordinate.latitude=51.5072;
        coordinate.longitude=0.1275;

        rmMapView.centerCoordinate=coordinate;

        [self.viewMapContainer addSubview:rmMapView];


        [self addAnnotations];



    }
```